# How to echo paths which are being merged in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, git-merge

I'm trying to merge a list of files from one branch to another.

I need the GitLab variable name which reflects the path being merged.

Does GitLab provide any predefined GitLab variable for this purpose? If not, what is the best way to echo the path being merged?

**what exactly I am trying to achieve :**

I'm trying to automate the merge process and for that , need to print the full path of the file which is being merged in the console output. something like "verbose" in command.

Comment: "merging files" is an action in `git`, not specific to gitlab (e.g : you can do a merge from the command line using `git` only). Can you explain in more details what you need to do with your files ?

Comment: added more explanation . please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a branch `feature`, and want to see what files will be merged in `master` if you were to merge `feature` into `master`, you can use :

```
git diff --name-only master...feature  # 3 dots
```

Comment: Thanks . so for this , does git uses any special/environment variable to store the path ? That way, I can use this variable in some workflow rules in gitlab for further processing

Comment: no, there isn't an environment variable with tthat content. You can write a script which runs this command and use its output